# AngularFirestore query with where clause returning same document more than once

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection with two documents and when I do query using where clause in this collection it returns the same document twice, if there are x documents in the collection it always returns the same document, but repeated x times the number of documents. How can I return the fetched document only once?

I have tried the following:

```
this.angulfirestore.collection('clients', ref=>ref.where
          ('name', '==', 'Pedro')).valueChanges().subscribe(
          (data)=>{
            data.forEach(e=>{
             let res = [];
              res.push(e);
               console.log(res); 
           });});
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How are you observing that you're getting multiple documents in a single set of query results?  Your code is using a database listener, which gets invoked every time the result set of the query changes.  Please edit the question to include more detail about your debugging observations. Perhaps you should log once at the top of your subscriber to show how many times it's being invoked.